など before an adverb?

あおいくんはへたり込むようにして席につき、ため息吐くなどげんなりだ。
Aoikun sits as if she was sitting on the floor and leaves out sighs dejected.

But why is など used here? Is it modifying げんなり?

It modifies ため息吐く. The など here implies that ため息吐く is only one of the things that あおいくん did that shows his げんなり (fed up) state of mind, and i.e. other manifestations of his fed-upness are not elaborated.
